# Can't restore from mysql dump file

Tags: mysql, java

I used mysqldump command to export/dump .sql file with rows like:

```
String cmd1 = mysqldump + " -h" + host + " -u" + username + " -p" + password + " " + "--compact --no-create-info " + "--where=ID=" + "'5b4ed36d-6152-4bfd-ad06-666f781e8bdc'" + " " + database + " " + "EMPLOYEE" + " " + "--result-file=" + "C:\\employee.sql";
```

This is the result of above command in a employee.sql file:

```
INSERT INTO `employee` VALUES ('Anette','Busch','2014-08-12','admin',' ','FALSE');
```

Now, I want to import the values from empolyee.sql file using command:

```
String cmd =  mysql + " --user=" + username + " --password=" + password +  " -e" + " source " + restoreFile;
```

The problem is I can't execute import command. I'm using the same import command for whole database, that works fine, but not in this case.

Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you forgot to put double quotes around the `-e` parameter

```
String cmd =  mysql + " --user=" + username + " --password=" + password +  " -e\"" + "source " + restoreFile + "\"";
```

An alternative would be to redirect the file into the  mysql client

```
String cmd =  mysql + " --user=" + username + " --password=" + password +  " < " + restoreFile;
```

I also just noticed that you forgot to set the target database

```
String cmd =  mysql + " --user=" + username + " --password=" + password +  " -D" + mydb + "-e\"" + "source " + restoreFile + "\""; 

String cmd =  mysql + " --user=" + username + " --password=" + password +  " -D" + mydb + "  < " + restoreFile;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I can't execute "<" in java.

Comment: You forgot to set the target database when importing. I updated my answer.

Comment: processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor(); The program gets stuck in this line. Doesn't return 0, which mean successful import.

Comment: Do you have the `EMPLOYEE` table already in the target database ? Is the target database on the same DB Server ?

Comment: Yes! I have it there... Target Database is also on the same DB Server.

Comment: Please post the string cmd (hiding the username and password)

Comment: My this command [mysql -u root -proot database < "employee.sql"] executes well in command prompt but when I write in query as mentioned by you, In both cases, It doesn't execute.

Comment: Your this command worked pretty well. The only problem was the space between -D and database, space between database and -e. The command the worked for me is: [String cmd =  mysql + " --user=" + username + " --password=" + password +  " -D " + database + " -e\"" + "source " + restoreFile + "\"";]

Comment: I don't know why the second command didn't work, thought I tried with many changes. But the bottom line is, Thanks for your help, it works fine!

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA is it also possible to do this not from a file (`< restoreFile`) but from a SQL string?